# How do I access the blob name from inside an azure function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Given the signature below, how can I access the value of `{name}` inside the code block?

For a simple example, I wish to log the name of the file added to the queue. Using the signature below, I get the image stream, as expected, but I don't see a way to access the filename `{name}` from the stream.

```
    [FunctionName("Foo")]
    public static void Run([BlobTrigger("%queue%/{name}")]Stream image,
      TraceWriter log)
      {
          *** Use the value of {name} here...
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    [FunctionName("Foo")]
    public static void Run([BlobTrigger("%queue%/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");

        string filename = name;
        log.Info(filename);
    }
```

Comment: This just works inside trace. You cannot get the name into a variable for instance.

Comment: @WagnerBertoliniJunior Are you sure? Have a look at the function bindings such as the input arguments - see MSDN doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob

Comment: I beg your pardon. I was having a difficult here that drove me to that answer, but you are completely right! Sorry!